# undefined method `comments' for #<Post:0x19f3d70>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just started to learn RoR and kind of stuck here. I was doing one of the guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).
I'm totally don't know how to debug Rails applications yet, so your advices are highly appreciated. Or probably you have came across this error before.

How do I debug this? where should I look at?

Comment: Have you been following the guide step by step? The Post class should have a `has_many :comments` for it to work, and depending on your setup restarting the Rails server may help.

Comment: @gnab great!! I missed the `has_many :comments` thanks!!

Comment: @gnab, how should I close this question? should you put your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably miss a `has_many :comments` in your `Post` class.

Now you may accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with rails 3.2.1 add :comments to attr_accessible

attr_accessible :text, :title, :comments